# Updating Values on Two Field Pairs Returning Strange Vlaues

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have the following query in my application to fix any unknown boxer ID's when a new boxer is added to my database. To make other queries and function in the system easier, when a bout is added `boxer_1` ID is always less than the `boxer_2` ID.

The below function seem to work perfectly to update/switch the `boxer_1` and `boxer_2` fields, but the `boxer_1_weight` and `boxer_2_weight` values get strange results and i can't work out why?

```
"UPDATE bouts b1, bouts b2 SET b1.unknown_global_id = 0,
                    b1.winner = IF(b2.winner = -3, IF(b1.boxer_1 = 0, '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_1), IF(b2.winner = -2, IF(b1.boxer_2 = 0, '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_2), b1.winner)),
                    b1.boxer_1 = IF(b1.boxer_1 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' > b1.boxer_2, b1.boxer_2, '" . $boxer_id . "'), IF(b1.boxer_1 < '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_1, '" . $boxer_id . "')), 
                    b1.boxer_2 = IF(b1.boxer_2 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' < b2.boxer_1, b2.boxer_1, '" . $boxer_id . "'), IF(b1.boxer_2 > '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_2, '" . $boxer_id . "')),
                    b1.boxer_1_weight = IF(b2.boxer_1 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' > b2.boxer_2, b2.boxer_2_weight, b2.boxer_1_weight), IF(b2.boxer_1 < '" . $boxer_id . "', b2.boxer_1_weight, b2.boxer_2_weight)),
                    b1.boxer_2_weight = IF(b2.boxer_2 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' < b2.boxer_1, b2.boxer_1_weight, b2.boxer_2_weight), IF(b2.boxer_2 > '" . $boxer_id . "', b2.boxer_2_weight, b2.boxer_1_weight))
                    WHERE b1.unknown_global_id = '" . (int)$global_id . "'"
```

`boxer_1/boxer_2` fields are INT(11) and `boxer_1_weight/boxer_2_weight` fields are decimal(10,1)

As an example, if the weight fields start with weights 186.5 and 199.7, after running the query they both end up as 239.8, but the boxer ID's are correct.

Comment: You don't seem to have a join condition relating the row in `b1` to a specific row in `b2`. So it's going to compare the selected row in `b1` to every row in `b2`.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking at it for hours and it turn out to be something so obviously simple :) `AND b1.bout_id = b2.bout_id` at the end did the trick. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you want to post it as an 'answer'. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join condition to avoid comparing the selected row in `b1` with every other row in `b2`.

```
"UPDATE bouts b1
        JOIN bouts b2 ON b1.bout_id = b2.bout_id
        SET b1.unknown_global_id = 0,
            b1.winner = IF(b2.winner = -3, IF(b1.boxer_1 = 0, '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_1), IF(b2.winner = -2, IF(b1.boxer_2 = 0, '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_2), b1.winner)),
            b1.boxer_1 = IF(b1.boxer_1 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' > b1.boxer_2, b1.boxer_2, '" . $boxer_id . "'), IF(b1.boxer_1 < '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_1, '" . $boxer_id . "')), 
            b1.boxer_2 = IF(b1.boxer_2 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' < b2.boxer_1, b2.boxer_1, '" . $boxer_id . "'), IF(b1.boxer_2 > '" . $boxer_id . "', b1.boxer_2, '" . $boxer_id . "')),
            b1.boxer_1_weight = IF(b2.boxer_1 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' > b2.boxer_2, b2.boxer_2_weight, b2.boxer_1_weight), IF(b2.boxer_1 < '" . $boxer_id . "', b2.boxer_1_weight, b2.boxer_2_weight)),
            b1.boxer_2_weight = IF(b2.boxer_2 = 0, IF('" . $boxer_id . "' < b2.boxer_1, b2.boxer_1_weight, b2.boxer_2_weight), IF(b2.boxer_2 > '" . $boxer_id . "', b2.boxer_2_weight, b2.boxer_1_weight))
        WHERE b1.unknown_global_id = '" . (int)$global_id . "'"
```